# Problem printing json data from python script

Tags: json, python-3.x, printing

I have a python script that should print json data.

This is what I have in my script:

```
 finaldata = {   
  "date": datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat(),
  "voltage_mv":emeter["voltage_mv"],
  "current_ma":emeter["current_ma"],
  "power_mw":emeter["power_mw"] ,
  "energy_wh": emeter["total_wh"],
    }

    print(finaldata)
```

I am running the script from Node-RED because I need to send the data to a storage account (in json format of course). The Problem is that the data that is being sent looks like this:

```
{'power_mw': 0, 'date': '2019-04-16T07:12:19.858159', 'energy_wh': 2, 'voltage_mv': 225045, 'current_ma': 20}
```

when it should look like this in order to be correctly stored in my storage account:

```
{"power_mw": 0, "date": '2019-04-16T07:12:19.858159', "energy_wh": 2, "voltage_mv": 225045, "current_ma": 20}
```

(important for later use, since I already get errors in the storage account).

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: The json object is transformed into a dictionary which depending on your python version the ordering is not guaranteed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dictionaries: How to keep keys/values in same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/dictionaries-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)

Comment: Both json you posted look the same? what is the difference you are trying to tell us?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh   I need a " and not a ' when printing. But the question is solved now. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the python json module and dump your python `dict` into `json`:

```
import json

finaldata = {"power_mw": 0, "date": '2019-04-16T07:12:19.858159',
             "energy_wh": 2, "voltage_mv": 225045, "current_ma": 20}

print(json.dumps(finaldata))
```

[JSON Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

For order check linked [OrderedDict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/dictionaries-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)
or read the [OrderedDict collection Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html)